# My app freeze when I try to refresh my window (detail inside)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem with my program in Tkinter.

I have added this code to my program:

```
def display():

  A1 = random.randint(1,7)
  A2 = random.randint(1,6)

  while True:
    Pion_Rouge_N(A1, A2)
    Pion_Jaune_N(A1, A2)
    time.sleep(5)
```

And when I run this code, my program freeze... I need to kill python3 with the killall command.

I saw this website but I can't apply this solution to my app: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.fr/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html

Here is my entire code: https://ghostbin.com/paste/7n5sw

Comment: Well you have a `while` loop that will never end, what did you expect? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a complete, minimal example that *actually recreates the issue*.

Comment: I want to display a token every 5 secs. Sorry, I'm a beginner... Thanks for the link

Comment: Why can't you apply the solution you linked to? What have you tried after reading that article? The first part describes pretty much exactly what your problem is.  Also, have you searched this site? This sort of question has been asked and answered several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple fix. Un-indent the last three lines and remove the while loop altogether. Then at the bottom of your code add something along the lines of `root.after(5000, display)` so that display will be called once every 5 seconds. `root` should be the variable that you have storedthe `Tk()` object you created in. Example of what this code should look like below:

```
def display():
    A1 = random.randint(1,7)
    A2 = random.randint(1,6)
    Pion_Rouge_N(A1, A2)
    Pion_Jaune_N(A1, A2)
    root.after(5000, display)
```